# Calculate the displayed part of a String in a Text() with .linelimit() in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have to display a very long String.
In the first line shall be some other UI Elements on the trailing edge (in my example a Button). Under the fist line, the rest of that string shall be displayed.

[image]

My approach was, to calculate the displayed part of that String in the first Text() with is limited with .linelimit(1). Then, I want to display the truncated part of the string in another Text(). I try like this, but have no idea, how to get the displayed part of the String in the first Text().

```
struct ContentView: View {
  let text = "this is a long Text, it shall be presented in two Textfields"
  var restOfText = "Text, it shall be presented in two Textfields"
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack (alignment: .leading){
      HStack{
        Text(text).lineLimit(1)
        Button("Do something!"){ print("something done")}
      }
      .padding(.vertical, 5)
      // calculate restOfText depending on presented part of the string in the first Text()
      Text(restOfText)
      .padding(.vertical, 5)
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(width: .infinity, height: .infinity)
  }
}
```

Any other idea how to do this?

Comment: Ok I'm going to ask the obvious, why are you going to show them in a separate text?

Comment: If you want this to wrap multiple lines, don't set a line limit. If you want it on one continuous axis, embed it in a `ScrollView`. If you want to adjust the alignment of the multi-line text, that's a slightly different question. You can also use the `+` operator on `Text`, which is similar to attributed strings.

Comment: Hmm... Thnx! I added a pic in the post, that shows, what I want to archive.

Comment: Any other ideas, how to solve the core problem?

Comment: You could try this using a `UITextView` instead and set the exclusion paths of its textContainer.